# Create fedora rpm that works with both upstart and systemd?

Tags: fedora, rpm, upstart

I've built a service and I'd like to distribute it via rpm and should work on different fedora releases. Since it is a service it should be integrated with the system so it is possible to do:

```
$ service myapp start
```

The problem is that fedora used **upstart** in releases 9 to 14 and **systemd** from 15 and up. I can do this for both systems, but I'm not sure how to package it correctly.

I think I have to build different rpms for the fedora releases. The only thing that differs is a few files to be copied to different locations.

How should I handle the differences? In the .spec-file or Makefile? Or should I use two different .spec-files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in the spec file. Use separate sources for the upstart and systemd scripts, and include the appropriate script [based on the version of Fedora being built on](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:DistTag). So, single spec file to handle both cases.